# openpyxl value error when writing to cell

Tags: python, openpyxl, valueerror

i'm trying to write a sum of my dataframe column to a cell via openpyxl

my code is:

```
 worksheet.cell(row=row, column=col+1).value = data
```

the value error raised is:

> raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
>
> ValueError: Cannot convert array([ 1427.09609]) to Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
worksheet.cell(row=row, column=col+1).value = data[0]
```

Comment: @Jason note that it worked because you were passing an array to the cell - `data[0]` grabs the element at position 0 of `data`, in your case a float, which can then be set as a cell value - I'm glad this helped!